# Error when adding field to custom lead convert page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting this error now that I added Lead Status Reason to my custom lead convert page: "The dependent picklist 'Lead Status Reason' requires its controlling field 'Lead Status' to be present on the page." Lead Status has always been on the page, I just added Lead Status Reason here:

```
<!-- Converted Status -->
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status" for="leadStatus" />
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
        <apex:selectList id="LeadStatusList" size="1" 
            value="{!LeadToConvert.Status}" multiselect="false" required="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!LeadStatusOption}"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status Reason" for="leadStatusReason" />
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="Input" layout="block">
            <div class="Block"></div>
            <apex:inputField value="{!LeadToConvert.Lead_Status_Reason__c}" required="false">
            </apex:inputField>  
        </apex:outputPanel>               
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by making Lead Status an apex:inputField instead of apex:selectList in order for it to be recognized on the page with the dependent field.